# How to use a svg file and change its color?

Tags: html, svg

The difference between my question and other questions is that other questions are solved using `JQuery` or `JavaScript`. But I want my problem to be solved **only with html**.

My main goal in this question is to get a piece of html code to use the `svg` file and change it to my own favorite color!

I have `home.svg` file. I am using this file as follows and I made this attempt to change its color.

```
<img src="home.svg" style="color: white" />
```

default color for `svg` is black, but **i want change that color to white or other colors**!

how can i solved this problem?

Comment: I think you want to eat soup with a fork :)

Comment: No, no, no, he wants to eat soup from a can **without** opening the can. JavaScript **is** required to open the can: https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd

Answer (score 2):

You can only change the color of an inline svg and would use `fill:` instead of `color:`.

However, when using `fill: currentColor;` it will use the `color` of the element.

```css
svg {
  fill: currentColor;
  color: red;
}
  
svg:hover {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" />
</svg>
```

If you don't want to inline the svg, alternatively you can `href` (formerly `xlink`) it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/href